# Add year to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a small issue with data cleaning. I have the `date/month` without the `year` and I want to add the year to it. I need to check if this date is from this year i.e. 2018 and if the month is January, February or March. If not check from 2017. My data is exactly from April 2017, hence I think this crude method will work, any suggestion will be appreciated. I have added my code but wondering if there is some nicer way to do this

```
Input: "15 March"
Desired output: "15 March 2018"
```

My code!

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil import parser
test = "15 March"
ico = parser.parse(test)
#print(ico.month)
today = date.today()
diff = abs(today.month - ico.month)
print(diff)
if diff <= 3:
  print(test + " 2018")
else:
  print(test + " 2017")
```

Comment: Which "crude method" are you talking about? It appears that you already have a working code, so consider posting on [codereview.se], but note that [don't crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and read their help center before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply keep the months in an array if you're sure about the months being in their full orientation.

```
>>> this_year = ['january', 'february', 'march']
>>> last_year = ['april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
>>> def add_year(input_date: str)-> str:
    month = input_date.split(' ')[-1]
        updated_date = f'{input_date} 2018' if month.lower() in this_year else f'{input_date} 2017'
    return updated_date

>>> add_year('25 march')
'25 march 2018'
>>> add_year('25 March')
'25 March 2018'
```